# Access to a "parent" object

Tags: c++, sfml

I am a beginner in C++ (in english to :P), and I tried to make a game of life with SFML. I created a class `Application` with an `EventManager` property. I were wondering how to access from the `Evenmanager` to the `Application` properties. I first tried to add a pointer to the `Application` instance, but I don't get how to do it. Is it a correct way to do it ?

EDIT : Now I got this code

```
// Application.h
#ifndef APP_H
#define APP_H

#include "EventManager.h"

class EventManager;

class Application
{
public:
    Application(void);
    ~Application(void);
    // ...
private:
    EventManager m_eventManager;
};

#endif

// EventManager.h
#ifndef EVENT_MGR_H
#define EVENT_MGR_H

#include "Application.h"

class Application;

class EventManager
{
public:
    EventManager::EventManager(Application* app) : m_app(app) {}
    ~EventManager(void){}
private:
    Application* m_app;
};

#endif
```

`Application:m_eventManager uses undefined class EventManager`, that's the only error I got.

Comment: I think it's good to add some code.

Comment: If you edit your question to show what you tried, I'm sure someone can help point out the mistakes you made and how they could be fixed.

Comment: Read stuff about forward declaration !

Comment: you probably have to make a forward declaration of the class Application

Comment: It's impossible to be sure from this incomplete example, but it looks as if `Application` and `EventManager` don't know about each other correctly. You must forward-declare `EventManager` in `Application.h`, and `#include "Application.h"` in `EventManager.h`. It wouldn't hurt to check your header guards while you're at it.

Comment: I updated my code with forward declaration, and the `#include "Application.h"` was here before. Checked the header guards, all is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have included a code example that shows and explains what you want.

EDIT: Removed old example, added this example with classes in seperate headers.

Application.hpp:

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_HPP
#define APPLICATION_HPP

#include "EventManager.hpp" // The EventManager.hpp file is pasted into this header, so it will technically look like the first example I showed.

class Application {
    EventManager _event_manager;
public:

    Application() : _event_manager(this) {

    }
};

#endif
```

EventManager.hpp

```
#ifndef EVENT_MANAGER_HPP
#define EVENT_MANAGER_HPP

#include <iostream>

class Application;

class EventManager {
    Application* _application;
public:
    EventManager(Application* _Application) {
        _application = _Application;
        std::cout << "Pointer to application: " << _application << std::endl;
    }
};

#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Application.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Application application;
    std::cin.get();
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. It now uses two seperate header files like your code does.

Comment: Oh thanks ! I just had to removed the #include "Application.h" in the EventManager.h to resolve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You have a circular dependency in your headers: each tries to include the other. The include guards mean that each will only be included once, but one definition will appear before the other. In this case, you end up with `Application` defined before `EventManager`; which is bad since it needs the definition of `EventManager` in order to declare the member variable.

Luckily, `EventManager` doesn't need the complete definition of `Application` since it only uses a pointer to that type; so you can remove the `#include "Application.h"` and just leave the declaration of `class Application;`